# xampp mysql tables doesn't exsist in the engine

Tags: mysql

today when I started the MySQL service from the xampp control panel it doesn't work and gives me this log

```
2022-08-07 17:07:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-08-07 17:07:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-08-07 17:07:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-08-07 17:07:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-08-07 17:07:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-08-07 17:07:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-08-07 17:07:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-08-07 17:07:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=304391
2022-08-07 17:07:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-08-07 17:07:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2022-08-07 17:07:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-08-07 17:07:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-08-07 17:07:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-08-07 17:07:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-08-07 17:07:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.22 started; log sequence number 304400; transaction id 177
2022-08-07 17:07:58 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-08-07 17:07:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-08-07 17:07:58 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2022-08-07 17:09:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-08-07 17:09:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-08-07 17:09:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-08-07 17:09:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-08-07 17:09:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-08-07 17:09:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-08-07 17:09:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-08-07 17:09:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=304739
2022-08-07 17:09:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-08-07 17:09:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2022-08-07 17:09:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-08-07 17:09:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-08-07 17:09:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-08-07 17:09:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-08-07 17:09:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.22 started; log sequence number 304748; transaction id 184
2022-08-07 17:09:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-08-07 17:09:17 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-08-07 17:09:17 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2022-08-07 17:11:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-08-07 17:11:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-08-07 17:11:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-08-07 17:11:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-08-07 17:11:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-08-07 17:11:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-08-07 17:11:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-08-07 17:11:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=305071
2022-08-07 17:11:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-08-07 17:11:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2022-08-07 17:11:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-08-07 17:11:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-08-07 17:11:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-08-07 17:11:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-08-07 17:11:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.22 started; log sequence number 305080; transaction id 170
2022-08-07 17:11:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-08-07 17:11:14 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-08-07 17:11:14 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

the problem is that I tried to reset the database files from `mysql/backup` and move it to the `mysql/data` file so after that the service worked successfully but when I logged in to phpmyadmin I get a message when trying to browse the database `test` tables that message is

`#1932 - Table 'test.accounts' doesn't exist in engine`

so I think that the database has been corrupted, is there any way to restore the database

Comment: This is a perfectly normal start of mysql, there is no warning or error. SO has tons of answers already how to restore mysql database from various formats - even though such questions should be asked on the DBA sister site ofSO.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether the table file exists, then dump the table and import it, or check it and then repair it with repire.